# Failure when passing a variable to a view CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I trying to pass $variable from CodeIgniter controller to a view but it's fail.

My controller code is:

```
class Index_controller extends CI_Controller {
    public function index(){
        $formURL = base_url().index_page().'authorization_controller/authorization';
        $attributes = array('class' => 'authorization','id' => 'authorization');
        $this->load->view('header');
        $this->load->view('leftFrame', $formURL, $attributes);
        $this->load->view('rightFrame');
        $this->load->view('index');
        $this->load->view('footer');
    }
}
```

My view code is:

```
<?php echo form_open($formURL, $attributes); ?>
</form>
```

Error message:

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined variable: formURL
```

and

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined variable: attributes
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the data in an array or an object. You can then access this data by referencing a variable of the same name as the array key in the view. You can achieve this like this:

```
public function index()
{
    $formURL = base_url().index_page().'authorization_controller/authorization';
    $attributes = array('class' => 'authorization','id' => 'authorization');

    // Data to pass to the view
    $view_data['formURL'] = $formURL;
    $view_data['attributes'] = $attributes;

    $this->load->view('header');
    $this->load->view('leftFrame', $view_data);
    $this->load->view('rightFrame');
    $this->load->view('index');
    $this->load->view('footer');
}
```

Comment: Oh, is that mean i shoud collect $variables in only one object before send it to a view? Like this:`$this -> load -> view ( 'leftFrame' , Object );` NOT: `$this -> load -> view ( 'leftFrame' , Object, Object, Object...... );` ?

Comment: Yes, there is only one parameter for passing data; you can pass either an array or object though. The [user guide](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/views.html) is very useful. :)

Comment: Ok now, I fully understand my mistake. Thank you for your help. PS: Yes i reading a guide, but this moment was troubled for me. PPS: This is my first post to the "Stack". ;)

Answer (score 0):

You need to not separate out the data you are sending to the views. You need to use CodeIgniters magic data array feature to do this.

**[CI Docs](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/views.html)**
Scroll to the secion labeled "Adding dynamic data to the view"

Try changing your code to the following...

```
class Index_controller extends CI_Controller {
    public function index(){
        $formURL = base_url().index_page().'authorization_controller/authorization';
        $attributes = array('class' => 'authorization','id' => 'authorization');

        //ADD Your variables to CodeIgniter Data Array
        $data["formURL"] = $formURL;
        $data["attributes"] = $attributes;

        $this->load->view('header');
        $this->load->view('leftFrame', $data);
        $this->load->view('rightFrame');
        $this->load->view('index');
        $this->load->view('footer');
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh, is that mean i shoud collect $variables in only one object before send it to a view? Like this:$this -> load -> view ( 'leftFrame' , Object ); NOT: $this -> load -> view ( 'leftFrame' , Object, Object, Object...... ); ?

Comment: Yes, you need to collect all of the variables / objects / arrays you ant to send to your view into a single array, and pass that single array to your view.